# Decimal number validate is not working with length

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to validate the decimal number pattern with specific length but no luck.

I tried this  `pattern="[0-9]){1,2}(\.){1}([0-9]){2}"` but this works only `12.12`

I'm looking for (13digits).(6digits) pattern validation and length validation.

Expected is,

```
      `1234567891123.123456` //true
      `1234567891123123456`  //false since only number
      `12345678911234.123456` //false since 14digits.6digits
      `1234567891123.1234567` //false since 13digits.7digits
```

What be the better regx to fulfill the above validations?

Comment: I suggest reading a tutorial on regex, changing two numbers should not be a difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

A useful site for regex testing is https://regexr.com/

```
\b\d{13}\.\d{6}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex that you need should be like this:

```
([0-9]){13}(\.){1}([0-9]){6}
```

So for example in HTML form input, it would look like this:

```html
<form action="">

  <input type="text" required pattern="([0-9]){13}(\.){1}([0-9]){6}" />

  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
\d{13}[.]\d{6}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo :**

```js
var regex = /^[0-9]{13}\.[0-9]{6}$/i;

function getValue()  {
    return document.getElementById("myinput").value;
}

function test() {
    alert(regex.test(getValue()));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput"/>
<button id="testBtn" onclick=test()>test</button>
```